# Combine two dataframes with seperate keys for one dataframe so can select two column based on keys

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want new column `DATE1` equal to a column `START` in dataframe1(DF1) on `KEY1` and combine with Dataframe2 (DF2) based on `KEY2` in DF2 so it shows DATE1 just when the key mayches in the join. I can show column start but it shows all.

I want DATE2 equal column `START` in dataframe1(DF1) on `KEY1` but combine with DF2 based on a diffrent key called `KEY3` in DF2 so it shows `DATE2` just when the key matches in the join. I can show column start but not sure how to only show colum start when combined on two keys.

Example input for DF1 would be:

```
+---------+--------+------+------+
|START    |KEY1    |Color  OTHER |
+---------+--------+------+------+
| 10/05/21|  1     | White|  3000|
| 10/06/21|  2     |  Blue|  4100|
| 10/07/21|  3     | Green|  6200|
+---------+--------+------+------+
```

DF2 input would be:

```
+---------+--------+----+
|KEY2     |KEY3 |NUMBER|
+---------+--------+----+
|  1     |     2|  3000 |
|  2     |     3|  4100 |
|  3     |     1|  6200 |
+---------+--------+----+
```

Output would be something like below:

```
+---------+--------+
|DATE1    | DATE2 |
+---------+--------+
| 10/05/21|10/06/21|       
| 10/06/21|10/07/21|       
| 10/07/21|10/05/21|      
+---------+--------+
```

Below is code

```
def transform_df_data(df: DataFrame):
        return \
            df \
                .withColumn("DATE1", col("START")) \
                .withColumn("DATE2", col("START")) \
                .withColumn("KEY1", col("KEY1")) \
                .select("KEY1","DATE1","DATE2")
    
    def build_final_df(df:DataFrame, otherdf:Dataframe)
         df_transform = transform_df_data(d_period)
         return final_transform.join(df_transform , final_transform.KEY1 == df_transform(KEY2, 'inner').withColumn("DATE1", col("START")).select("DATE1","DATE2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note sure I correctly understand the question, but I think you want to join `df1` and `df2` on `KEY1 = KEY2` then join the result again with `df1` on `KEY1 = KEY3`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data1 = [("10/05/21", 1, "White", 3000), ("10/06/21", 2, "Blue", 4100), ("10/07/21", 3, "Green", 6200)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["START", "KEY1", "Color", "OTHER"])

data2 = [(1, 2, 3000), (2, 3, 4100), (3, 1, 6200)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["KEY2", "KEY3", "NUMBER"])

df_result = df1.withColumnRenamed("START", "DATE1").join(
    df2,
    F.col("KEY1") == F.col("KEY2")
).select("DATE1", "KEY3").join(
    df1.withColumnRenamed("START", "DATE2"),
    F.col("KEY1") == F.col("KEY3")
).select("DATE1", "DATE2")

df_result.show()

#+--------+--------+
#|   DATE1|   DATE2|
#+--------+--------+
#|10/07/21|10/05/21|
#|10/05/21|10/06/21|
#|10/06/21|10/07/21|
#+--------+--------+
```