# Join two dataframes using three seperate keys

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data1 = [("10/05/21", 1, "White", 3000), ("10/06/21", 2, "Blue", 4100), ("10/07/21", 3, "Green", 6200)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["START", "KEY1", "Color", "OTHER"])

data2 = [(1, 2, 3, 3000), (2, 3, 2, 4100), (3, 1, 2, 6200)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["KEY2", "KEY3", "KEY4", "NUMBER"])

df_result = df1.withColumnRenamed("START", "DATE1").join(
    df2,
    F.col("KEY1") == F.col("KEY2")
).select("DATE1", "KEY3", "KEY4").join(
    df1.withColumnRenamed("START", "DATE2"),
    F.col("KEY1") == F.col("KEY3")
).select("DATE1", "DATE2", "KEY4").join(
    df1.withColumnRenamed("START", "DATE3"),
    F.col("KEY1") == F.col("KEY4")
).select("DATE1", "DATE2", "DATE3")

df_result.show()
```

I am trying to use approach found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912678/combine-two-dataframes-with-seperate-keys-for-one-dataframe-so-can-select-two-co) but cannot seem to join it as says cannot resolve `key4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not selected `KEY4` after the first join making it unavailable for the `select` after the join with condition `KEY1 = KEY3`.

```
df_result = df1.withColumnRenamed("START", "DATE1").join(
    df2,
    F.col("KEY1") == F.col("KEY2")
).select("DATE1", "KEY3", "KEY4").join(
    df1.withColumnRenamed("START", "DATE2"),
    F.col("KEY1") == F.col("KEY3")
).select("DATE1", "DATE2", "KEY4").join(
    df1.withColumnRenamed("START", "DATE3"),
    F.col("KEY1") == F.col("KEY4")
).select("DATE1", "DATE2", "DATE3")
```

### Output

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|   DATE1|   DATE2|   DATE3|
+--------+--------+--------+
|10/05/21|10/06/21|10/07/21|
|10/07/21|10/05/21|10/06/21|
|10/06/21|10/07/21|10/06/21|
+--------+--------+--------+
```